# Static methods between 2 instances of the same application

Tags: c#, static-methods

I have written an application in C#. 
Several methods are static.
We run several of the C# applications at the same time.

Fact: Two of my colleagues told me that if we run 2 or more of this C# application that has these static methods, the application will slow down because each application has to share the static methods between each instance of the application.

I think this is totally incorrect and wanted to get others opinion on this.

Will running 2 or more instances of the same C# application that has static methods slow down due to the statement that the applications must "share" the static methods ?

Comment: I'd ignore future advice of your colleagues.

Comment: In event of emergency...do not follow your colleagues :)

Comment: I'm more baffled that they latched onto *speed*, not any of the typical dangers associated with shared/static members, like thread safety.

Comment: I was really baffled when I heard them say this but wanted to double check it before proceeding. There is always new stuff to learn but tis one was a bit far fetched.

Comment: Too funny LOLbut true : In event of emergency...do not follow your colleagues :) –  MailmanOdd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your coworkers are totally incorrect.

Joking aside, each application will load the assembly with the static methods. They're not really "sharing" anything except the same library reference. For example, windows applications surely share calls to many of the same static methods yet they are not (ostensibly) slowed down by this.

Comment: Much thanks MailmanOdd and all for your response. I'll have to use a kind of "bed side manner" to relate this to my colleagues so if anyone has an in debt analysis / explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mailman is right.
If you have multiple instances of a class *within the same running instance of a program* then static members/variables are shared between those class instances, although still won't cause you to slow down.